# Rails4 authorization strategies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-authorization

When it comes to Authorization/Authentication devise + cancan are usually my gems of choice.
After the release of Rails4's strong parameters I've been looking into using the [cancan_strong_parameters](https://github.com/colinyoung/cancan_strong_parameters) gem.

I can't shake the feeling that this approach seems a bit 'hacky'.
The other options seems to be [TheRole](https://github.com/the-teacher/the_role) gem or simply rolling my own auth from scratch.

Was hoping anyone with first hand experience here could give a few pointers on how they tackled the problem, what problems the faced and where each approach fell short (if anywhere).

I know this isn't a clean cut StackOverflow typed question, but there doesn't seem to be much info regarding this subject when Googling. 
Thanks.

Comment: I think (not that I will write a better alternative but still) that this gem is just poorly written. One can make an assumption that strong params "filter" method will be `singular_model_params` and just call it in execution of CanCan (+ add an option to provide different method name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read the discussion in [PR 763 "support for strong_parameters"](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/pull/763)?

In short, until `cancan 2` comes out, some people are using [Oliver Morgan's fork](https://github.com/ollym/cancan).

Comment: Thanks for that. Wasn't aware of Oliver Morgan's fork. I'm guessing the correct branch to use would be 'ollym_changes' right?

Answer (score 2):

There's also the protector gem:

https://github.com/inossidabile/protector

And cancancan:

https://github.com/bryanrite/cancancan

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the_role gem](https://github.com/the-teacher/the_role) which works in Rails 4 and is a CanCan replacement

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Cancancan based on:

- It's based on Cancan, the most widely used Authorization Rails library (until Rails 4)
- It's Rails 4 compatible
- It has more Commits, Contributors and Releases on Github than other Rails 4 authorization gems (The_Role, Pundit, etc.)
- It's has more downloads on rubygems.org than The_Role even though it has fewer downloads than Pundit